# Reputation needed to edit questions asked by someone else

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, edits

The faq clearly states that you need 2000 reputation to edit someone else's question, however I just saw a question edited by someone with 1043 reputation ([How to print string association from phone number as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858237/how-to-print-string-association-from-phone-number-as-text)). Is the faq wrong?

Comment: Clearly stated on the FAQ: **500** - Retag questions

Comment: Well the OP obviously misread/misunderstood the FAQ, no need for a down-vote yea? Whether editing or re-tagging, the text is the same, i.e "**edited xx mins ago**". Unless one clicks to view the revision, we can't really tell it is content editing or just tag editing.

Comment: Which is quicker, clicking the Edited by link or asking a question? (The latter) How about the user has ~700+ rep on SO and should also be seeing retag option on questions now?

Comment: Actually, I've never (until now) realized the "x minutes ago" was clickable and gave you a nice editing history. I'm learning more from this question than I expected.

Comment: Well, if a user didn't realise something is click-able or what's the click is for, it might be an usability issue. I'm not saying this is the case, just felt the down-vote is rather 'harsh'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. At 500 rep you can edit tags.

Comment: Didn't realize retaggin spawned the edited by doodle.

Answer (score 3):

The person just edited the tags.  This requires less than 2k reputation (only 500).